# How to ceate a reminder application in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reminders

Im working on a project where the employees in my organization will have to set a reminder to make a call to the clients or customers. Lets say if the customer asks for a callback at 12pm the employee will set the reminder at 11:55am and so on.

Im storing the date and time when the reminder has to be shown inside the table. Also i have to implement the snooze like functionality to extend the time lets say to 10 mins later.

I could have achieved it if it had been a windows based application, but my requirement is to get it done in Web Application(asp.net c#).

Im little bit confused about achieving this. I have Googled but couldn't find anything related to my requirement.

How should i compare the current date/time with the date/time in the table and make some notification, also this application would be always running, i mean the employees would be entering the datas so i woudn't consider any page reload.

Also i want to display the numbers of reminders that are pending or the number of reminders that has been missed as soon as the employee logins.

I found some ideas that i should be using .asmx file to get this done. But any clear guidance would be really useful.

Hope im not proceeding on the wrong track.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: So what's the problem here?

Comment: Why using a Web Application? It won't display pop-up notifications or toast in tray etc? Unless users have the web page open they will not be notified and relies on them constantly checking web-page which makes it pretty pointless?

Comment: @user2353972: is there any controll in ajax that can help me achieve this?

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih: Just any guidance on how to achieve this.

Comment: @Vikneshwar:just write the javascript code,i think it is easy,or you can use the jQuery.js.

Comment: @Belogix: Its ok even if i get the notification after the user logs in or opens the browser. But Im in the middle of the things and just missing the part of getting the reminders. Just any idea on how to get get the matching of the current time and the time in the table automatically.

Comment: @user2353972: Javascript? But how can i match the date in the table using javascript?

Comment: I would periodically check the current Time/Date with a timer/thread, by using the `DateTime` class.
Then if it's a hit I would simply open a notification window and bring it to front by using JavaScript with something like: `var w = window.open ("url","winName","location=0,width=300,height=214");
w.focus();`.

Comment: @Vikneshwar:use the javascript to request the server every few minutes,and match the time on server.

Comment: Thank U @JanesAbouChleih,@user2353972. Ill try doing it and see if i can achieve this.

Comment: i believe the right answer is take each users alert time and start a hidden countdown on javascript and on countodwn finish open the desired alert page. Happy coding